# How do you deploy DC/OS onto openstack?

Tags: openstack, dcos

How do you deploy dc/os on openstack? I found one answer on github but there isn't much information. Could someone please provide a step by step instruction?

Answer (score 4):

There currently aren't OpenStack-specific instructions for installing DC/OS. You would just treat the OpenStack VMs like any other baremetal server or generic VM running CentOS or CoreOS.

The recommended way for these installs is the Advanced Installer: https://docs.mesosphere.com/latest/installing/oss/custom/advanced/

Comment: Just to expand on this a little bit... I might also look into the community supported terraform code and add support for "openstack".

https://github.com/dcos/terraform-dcos

Comment: Could you write down step by step instructions for baremetal servers please.

Comment: The link is not available any more, I couldn't find a new one.

Comment: The new link advanced configuration link is at https://docs.mesosphere.com/latest/installing/production/advanced-configuration/

But as Jeffery mentioned, there are also the Terraform scripts. A PR for using OpenStack was opened in July but has not yet been reviewed, but it may make for a good starting point: https://github.com/dcos/terraform-dcos/pull/65